# My Xamarin.Android app on google play keeps updating .

Tags: android, xamarin

I made an application on xamarin android and send it to the google play . When I download the application , there are 2 option on google play , 
one of them is Remove, the other one is Update. It should be Remove and Open. When I tap update, app downloading again. After that remove and update shows up on google play again.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the play store. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/a2qtxi/why_does_my_game_let_you_update_it_in_perpetuity/

Comment: Thanks Castro, i just remove the app from the Google play and upload again , fixed.

Answer (score 1):

google forum discussions suggest that deploying a new version solves the bug

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/ZLJW1jQObf4

Comment: can you please  upvote/accept as answer @İsmailÇapkın?